# Possible harms of white noise

Tags: sleep, risks, hearing, earplugs-earphones, white-noise

I am having problems sleeping because of loud neighbours. There isn't a diplomatic way to solve this. So I went looking for ways to make sleeping easier with noise, and I came across [this answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7200/sleeping-in-a-noisy-environment/7217#7217) in lifehacks.stackexchange, which suggests the use of white noise to mask the outside noise. And I understand that the way to do it would be just put some headphones or earphones, keep it playing and go for it.

This solution caught my attention, but I have worries such as becoming dependent on it to sleep, or having my hearing damaged because of it. Another quick research lead me to [this page](http://www.slate.com/articles/double_x/the_kids/2014/03/sound_machine_study_should_not_cause_parents_to_panic_white_noise_doesn.html), and [this answer](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3855/are-there-any-dangers-or-downsides-to-white-noise-as-a-calming-tool) on parenting.stackexchange, which concern only babies and is not exactly of my interest (I found the answers there too specific for babies).

I figured here would be a more appropriate place to ask and receive a more specific answer and information about the subject:

> What are the risks caused by prolonged use of white noise to sleep?

Comment: This has been asked and answered here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/long-term-effect-of-using-noise-generators

Comment: I'm closing this question because it has already been answered on Cogsci.Se: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/long-term-effect-of-using-noise-generators Because you have not received any answers, I would recommend you check out that question to find an answer.